# Detect if email has an attachment

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, attachments

We have a document library where we store emails as documents.
Some of these emails have attachments.
Is there any way to detect if an already-stored-in-sharepoint email has an attachment?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint does not extract metadata from emails and is not aware if an email has an attachment or not.

You may want to use the size of the email as an indicator for the presence of an attachment but that is not very accurate. You may get false positives.

Another approach is to use apps that display the email in a browser and also allow viewing of the email attachments ([example](https://www.slimapplications.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/EmailManagerViewWordAttachment.png)). This method may be useful if the number of emails is not too high.

If you have lots of emails (100's or 1000's or more) then you need tools/scripts to parse each email and determine if there is an attachment or not.

What format are the emails in? msg, eml or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You confirmed my fear: Sharepoint is not aware of any attachment. Going forward we are using Aspose to check for the existence of an attachment, then setting a custom metadata field. To back fill the metadata we will have to download all the old emails. Good times!

Comment: One suggestion: assess the impact on your storage quota. Changing metadata yields a new version. FYI: we are working on a similar case where we need to extract email metadata (To, From, Subject, Attachments, ...) from tons of emails already present in SharePoint.